# VB application asks for SQL username and password

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008

When opening up our software on a user's machine, it asks for SQL Username and Password?

This is annoying, how would we fix this?

Comment: Our Software means? Describe your problem clearly.....

Comment: Hi Srinath. We have desktop program that connects to a sql server database. All the users can connect to the server. 1 specific user can open the software, BUT it asks for the sql server credentials before it get to the users login screen for our software

Answer (score 0):

As "your software" is running in Windows you can add the users' Windows accounts to SQL Server and then use [Windows Authentication](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd787978.aspx) to log them in.

Without more information about your code it's hard to give specific advice.